# Running mysql command in a while loop

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a list of mysql databases, and I wish to export a couple of tables from databases whose name ends in "_abc" using a linux script. However, I keep getting the error "Unexpected end of file".

This is my script, where `DB_FILE` is a text file containing the database names of those that end in "_abc".

```
while read db_name;
do
    OUT_FILENAME="${db_name}_table.csv"
    mysql -u$MYSQLUSER -p$MYSQLPASS -h $MYSQLHOST $db_name << EOFMYSQL
    SELECT * FROM table_abc INTO OUTFILE '$OUT_FILENAME' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
    EOFMYSQL
done < $DB_FILE

rm -f $DB_FILE
```

If I remove the 3 MYSQL lines, then the script runs without error.

Another question, if I have 2 `SELECT` queries, do I have to run each query separately, i.e. each enclosed by the `EOFMYSQL` statements, or can I have both queries within one `EOFMYSQL` block?

Comment: Heredoc is not the best approach here.. Update in a moment

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must have the `EOFMYSQL` without spaces before it: do not indent that one only.

```
while read db_name;
do
    OUT_FILENAME="${db_name}_table.csv"
    mysql -u$MYSQLUSER -p$MYSQLPASS -h $MYSQLHOST $db_name << EOFMYSQL
    SELECT * FROM table_abc INTO OUTFILE '$OUT_FILENAME' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
EOFMYSQL
done < $DB_FILE

rm -f $DB_FILE
```

In some appropriate text editor, it will show up easily, here notepad++:

### right indent:

[image: notepad++ right indent]

### wrong indent:

[image: notepad++ wrong indent]

Answer (score 2):

`$OUT_FILENAME` will not expand inside single quotes.

I guess you could put the query inside an array like below:

```
MYQUERY=( SELECT \* FROM table_abc INTO OUTFILE "$OUT_FILENAME" FIELDS TERMINATED BY \",\" LINES TERMINATED BY \"\\n\"\; )
```

and then change the `mysql` command to :

```
mysql -u"$MYSQLUSER" -p"$MYSQLPASS" -h "$MYSQLHOST" -e "${MYQUERY[@]}" "$db_name"
```

---

**Sidenotes**

1. I have double quoted all the variables to avoid word splitting.
2. Note that we wish to recreate actual query here. So you need to escape those characters which have special meaning here like `\*`,`\"` and so.